# Showing linebreaks in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I store the linebreaks as "line\n\nline" in the database.

When i am displaying it, I convert it using this method:

```
  def showLineBreaks(from_textarea) 
   from_textarea.gsub(/\n/,"<br/>")
  end
```

But these renders the text as

```
line<br><br>line
```

instead of showing the linebreaks.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to flag your content as `html_safe` for it to display properly, otherwise the view will render it as the string should be displayed.

```
<%= showLineBreaks.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to display newlines saved from text areas, you could do the following in your view:

```
<%= simple_format from_textarea %>
```

No need to do manual substitution in this case.